# Calculate previous balance and debit credit balance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have below table using sql server

```
 AccID        InvDate     Debit      Credit       Remark
----------- ----------- --------- --------- ---------------
Salary_Exp   28-1-2017     1000         0     Pay salary M1
Cash         28-1-2017        0      1000     Pay salary M1
Salary_Exp   28-2-2017     2000         0     Pay salary M2
Cash         28-2-2017        0      2000     Pay salary M2
Salary_Exp   29-3-2017     1500         0     Pay salary M3
Cash         29-3-2017        0      1500     Pay salary M3
Salary_Exp   30-4-2017     1000         0     Pay salary M4
Cash         30-4-2017        0      1000     Pay salary M4
Salary_Exp   28-5-2017     3000         0     Pay salary M5
Cash         28-5-2017        0      3000     Pay salary M5
Salary_Exp   30-6-2017     1500         0     Pay salary M6
Cash         30-6-2017        0      1500     Pay salary M6
```

I want to calculate and display the balance for each record as shown below
when i determines from date to date and AccID 
for example
determines from 29-3-2017 To 28-5-2017 and AccId=Salary_Exp
I want show below table

```
InvDate   Remark  Debit   Credit   Balance 
-----------    -----------    ---------   ---------   --------- 
-           previous Balance                      3000
29-3-2017   Pay salary M3     1500         0      4500
30-4-2017   Pay salary M4     1000         0      5500
28-5-2017   Pay salary M5     3000         0      8500
```

i am use stored procedure

```
Create proc Entries_StatementOfAccount
@FromDate date,
@ToDate date,
@AccID nvarchar(15)
AS
SELECT InvDate,Remark,Debit,Credit,SUM(Debit-Credit) AS Balance
FROM Entries 
WHERE  AccID=@AccID and (InvDate between @FromDate and @ToDate)
ORDER BY InvDate
```

Can anyone please help me ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess you're looking for `SUM(Debit-Credit) OVER (ORDER BY InvDate)`?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZZx5.jpg   My table

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADIkz.jpg   Result